# How does the Imp Logical Operator Work in VBA?

Tags: vba

I came across some code in VBA & I'm trying to understand how it works, but I've never encountered this operator.

What exactly does Imp operator do in VBA?

```
   If (a <> 0 Imp b = 0) Then
      MsgBox ("IMP Operator Result is : True")
   Else
      MsgBox ("IMP Operator Result is : False")
   End If
```

Are there examples of when we would use it?

Obviously, this is not a bitwise comparison, but something else.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/imp-operator this was litteraly the first google hit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic  because of total lack of research.

Comment: Its implication. You can find more information on link as @Luuklag  mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/imp-operator) from the comment actually is not that good. This is what it says:

> The Imp operator performs a bitwise comparison of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions and sets the corresponding bit in result according to the following table.

If you take a look at the example:

[image]

You would see that the result is always `True`(or 1) in any possible cases but one. The single case, where the result is `False` (or 0) is when the first operand is `True` and the second operand is `False`.